# Count only currently active threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list of Thread and I want to count only currently active threads, but method isAlive() don't work. How correctly is this or exist other method check for currently active threads.

```
public int activeSize() {
            int count = 0;
    
            for (Thread thread : list) {
                if (thread.isAlive()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
    
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Active"? Do you mean currently running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Compare the state of the thread:

```
thread.getState().equals( Thread.State.RUNNABLE )
```

Here is an example making a stream from your list of `Thread` objects.

```
threads
.stream()
.filter( 
    thread -> thread.getState().equals( Thread.State.RUNNABLE ) 
)
.count()  // Or collect them: `.toList()`
```

Or count all active threads:

```
Thread.activeCount()
```

## Details

I have no experience in this, but looking the Javadoc for [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html), I see [`getState`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getState()). That method returns a [`Thread.State`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html) enum object. Documentation says:

A thread can be in one of the following states, as quoted from the doc:

- `NEW`
  A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
- [`RUNNABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE)
  A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
- `BLOCKED`
  A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
- `WAITING`
  A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
- `TIMED_WAITING`
  A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
- `TERMINATED`
  A thread that has exited is in this state.

So loop your `Thread` objects, fetch their `State`, and see if it is [`RUNNABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE).

```java
for ( Thread thread : list) {
    if ( thread.getState().equals( Thread.State.RUNNABLE ) ) {
        …
    }
}
```

But if you just want a count of all active threads, call [`Thread.activeCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount()).

Answer (score 0):

This function counts all the active Threads in the process:

```java
java.lang.Thread.activeCount();
```

And of course, you could use `getState()` instead of `isActive()` to check the current thread's state.